# Background image not showing on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, background-image

Does any body know why the following CSS cannot show my background image on Safari. Please note that this CSS shows my background images on other browsers:

```
.thGridColumnHeader
{
    background-image: url('../Images/Textures/glass.png');
    background-image: none,-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,.12) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.08) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.05) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100%);
    background-image: none,-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,.12) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.08) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.05) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100%);
    background-image: none,-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,.12) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.08) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.05) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100%);
    background-image: none,linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,.12) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.08) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.05) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100%);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}
```

Here is the output on other browsers

[image]

Here is the output on safari

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved my problem by making the following tweak at the CSS class.

```
.thGridColumnHeader
{
    background-image: none,-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,.12) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.08) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.05) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100%);
    background-image: none,-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,.12) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.08) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.05) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100%);
    background-image: none,-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,.12) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.08) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.05) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100%);
    background-image: none,linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,.12) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.08) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.05) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100%);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
    background-image: url('../Images/Textures/glass.png');
}
```

I had transferred the code below to the last portion of the CSS class and it worked.

```
    background-image: url('../Images/Textures/glass.png');
```

Here is the output now on safari:

[image]

Comment: @VijayRamamurthy it says I have to wait for two days.

Comment: I have found solution thanks to your answare, but I have additional issue, I add the background image programatically, so I CAN NOT put the "background-image css" at the bottom, do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with parallax background image under Safari. I solved it by adding z-index to style

```
z-index:-1;
```